# Removing soft hyphens from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, soft-hyphen

Let's say I have a string that is littered with soft hyphens (pretend that the hyphens in the text below are soft hyphens):

```
T-h-i-s- -i-s- -a- -t-e-s-t-.-
```

I want to remove the soft hyphens and only return the string of:

```
This is a test.
```

I'm trying to do this in JavaScript.  Below is the farthest I have gotten so far:

```
RemoveSoftHyphen: function (text) {
    var result = text.match(/[^\uA00AD].*/);
    alert (result);
    return result;
}
```

When the alert displayed, all I got was a "-", which I'm not sure whether thats a soft or hard hyphen... but more importantly, it didn't work.

I'm trying to find out what is wrong with my regex, or is there a better approach to removing soft hyphens which I'm not aware of using either JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: Where in the code does the string get inserted back into the DOM?

Comment: @Hamish: this is a function that would be called by something else. The matching of the soft hyphen is the most worrying part, as I'm out of ideas on exactly how to get rid of those ninja hyphens and return me the sanitized string.

Comment: But *"the returning string doesn't contain any soft hyphens anymore"*. It's not clear what you're asking. Perhaps create an example at jsfiddle.com

Comment: What you want to do is - Remove a hyphen from a string, is it?

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. I have updated the question.  Hopefully it'll be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming that the character really is Unicode 00AD:

```
var result = text.replace(/\u00AD/g,'');
```

If you have [many hyphens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Unicode) to kill, use a character class:

```
var result = text.replace(/[\u00AD\u002D\u2011]+/g,'');
```