# dash(-) is converted to &shy; when pasted to input type text

Tags: javascript, html, sql-server-2008

I have a data from SQL Server, data's with dashes in them because it's a code. Using query thrown by AngularJS, somehow few of these codes returns without dashes based on my console.log().

i.e.
SQL Server Data

```
    Code | Description
    CPS-010 | Creston power spray 10m
    CPS-020 | Creston power spray 20m
    CPL-010 | Creston angle valve
```

But when consoled.log()

```
    Code | Description
    CPS-010 | Creston power spray 10m
    CPS-020 | Creston power spray 20m
    CPL010 | Creston angle valve
```

And when displayed in HTML Table and inspected it's elements.

```
    CPS-010 | Creston power spray 10m
    CPS-020 | Creston power spray 20m
    CPL&shy;010 | Creston angle valve
```

I have tried using replace(ItemCode,'-','-') in my query but doesn't work.

Comment: `&shy;` is the [soft-hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen), Unicode `0xAD`.

Comment: Can you post the link if your saying this is a duplicate question

Comment: The link is at the top -- [Removing soft hyphens from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380366/removing-soft-hyphens-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml):

```
<div ng-bind-html="expression"></div>
```

From Docs:

> You may also bypass sanitization for values you know are safe. To do
>   so, bind to an explicitly trusted value via [$sce.trustAsHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml). See the
>   example under [Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#show-me-an-example-using-sce-).